# Optimize Java differencing XML algorithm

Tags: java, xml

I am currently working on an algorithm capable of differencing two XML files. However, this algorithm turns out to be super slow when it comes to dealing with long XML files. Would you have any ideas how to optimize it ?

```
package comparison;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;

public class XmlDiff {
    private ArrayList<String> differences;
    private Document oldXml;
    private Document newXml;
    private Document configuration;
    private ArrayList<String> idDefinitions;

    public XmlDiff(Document oldXml, Document newXml, Document configuration) {
        this.differences = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.oldXml = oldXml;
        this.newXml = newXml;
        this.configuration = configuration;
        this.idDefinitions = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.configuration.getRootElement().getChild("Definition_id").getChildren().size(); i++) {
            idDefinitions.add(this.configuration.getRootElement().getChild("Definition_id").getChildren().get(i).getAttributeValue("Id_def"));
        }
    }

    public Document getOldXml() {
        return this.oldXml;
    }

    public Document getNewXml() {
        return this.newXml;
    }

    public Document getConfiguration() {
        return this.configuration;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getDifferences() {
        return differences;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getIdDefinitions() {
        return this.idDefinitions;
    }

    public boolean diffNodeName(Node oldNode, Node newNode) {
        if (oldNode.getNodeName().toLowerCase() == null && newNode.getNodeName().toLowerCase() == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (oldNode.getNodeName().toLowerCase() == null && newNode.getNodeName().toLowerCase() != null) {
            return true;
        }

        if (oldNode.getNodeName().toLowerCase() != null && newNode.getNodeName().toLowerCase() == null) {
            return true;
        }

        if (!oldNode.getNodeName().toLowerCase().equals(newNode.getNodeName().toLowerCase())) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean diffNodeAttributes(Node oldNode, Node newNode) {
        HashMap<String, String> oldAttributesHashMap = oldNode.buildHashMapFromAttributes();
        HashMap<String, String> newAttributesHashMap = newNode.buildHashMapFromAttributes();

        Set oldEntrySet = oldAttributesHashMap.entrySet();
        Iterator oldIter = oldEntrySet.iterator();

        while (oldIter.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry oldMe = (Map.Entry) oldIter.next();
            if (newAttributesHashMap.get(oldMe.getKey()) != null && oldAttributesHashMap.get(oldMe.getKey()).toLowerCase().equals(newAttributesHashMap.get(oldMe.getKey()).toLowerCase())) {
                oldIter.remove();
                oldAttributesHashMap.remove(oldMe.getKey());
                newAttributesHashMap.remove(oldMe.getKey());
            }
        }
        return !(oldAttributesHashMap.isEmpty() && newAttributesHashMap.isEmpty());
    }

    public void diffNodeValue(Node oldNode, String oldPath, Node newNode, String newPath) {
        if (oldNode.getValue() == null && newNode.getValue() != null) {
            this.getDifferences().add("value modified : " + oldPath + " } " + newPath + " : " + oldNode.getValue() + " changed to " + newNode.getValue());
        }

        if (oldNode.getValue() != null && newNode.getValue() == null) {
            this.getDifferences().add("value modified : " + oldPath + " } " + newPath + " : " + oldNode.getValue() + " changed to " + newNode.getValue());
        }

        if (!oldNode.getValue().equals(newNode.getValue())) {
            this.getDifferences().add("value modified : " + oldPath + " } " + newPath + " : " + oldNode.getValue() + " changed to " + newNode.getValue());
        }
    }

    public void compare(Node oldRoot, String oldPath, Node newRoot, String newPath) {
        if (oldRoot.hasChildren() && newRoot.hasChildren()) {
            String memoryOldPath = oldPath;
            String memoryNewPath = newPath;
            HashMap<Integer, Node> oldChildren = oldRoot.buildHashMapFromChildren();
            HashMap<Integer, Node> newChildren = newRoot.buildHashMapFromChildren();

            Set oldEntrySet = oldChildren.entrySet();
            Iterator oldIter = oldEntrySet.iterator();

            while (oldIter.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry oldMe = (Map.Entry) oldIter.next();
                int actualIndex = 0;
                Set newEntrySet = newChildren.entrySet();
                Iterator newIter = newEntrySet.iterator();
                Node actualOldChild = oldChildren.get(oldMe.getKey());
                boolean matched = false;
                boolean valueChanged = false;
                boolean attributesChanged = false;

                while (!matched && newIter.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry newMe = (Map.Entry) newIter.next();
                    Node actualNewChild = newChildren.get(newMe.getKey());
                    if (actualOldChild.getNodeName().toLowerCase().equals(actualNewChild.getNodeName().toLowerCase())) {
                        if (actualOldChild.getHasSimilarSiblings() || actualNewChild.getHasSimilarSiblings()) {
                            if (actualOldChild.hasAttributes() || actualNewChild.hasAttributes()) {
                                if (!this.diffNodeAttributes(actualOldChild, actualNewChild)) {
                                    if (actualOldChild.hasChildren() && actualNewChild.hasChildren()) {
                                        int oldResult = this.findIdChild(actualOldChild.getElement().getChildren());
                                        if (oldResult != -1) {
                                            matched = actualOldChild.getElement().getChildren().get(oldResult).getValue().toLowerCase().equals(actualNewChild.getElement().getChildren().get(oldResult).getValue().toLowerCase());
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            matched = true;
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        matched = true;
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    attributesChanged = true;
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (actualOldChild.hasChildren() && actualNewChild.hasChildren()) {
                                    int oldResult = this.findIdChild(actualOldChild.getElement().getChildren());
                                    if (oldResult != -1) {
                                        matched = actualOldChild.getElement().getChildren().get(oldResult).getValue().toLowerCase().equals(actualNewChild.getElement().getChildren().get(oldResult).getValue().toLowerCase());
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        matched = true;
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    matched = ((actualOldChild.getValue().toLowerCase() != null && actualNewChild.getValue().toLowerCase() != null&& actualOldChild.getValue().toLowerCase().equals(actualNewChild.getValue().toLowerCase()))|| (actualOldChild.getValue().toLowerCase() == null&& actualNewChild.getValue().toLowerCase() == null));
                                    valueChanged = ((actualOldChild.getValue().toLowerCase() != null && actualNewChild.getValue().toLowerCase() != null && !actualOldChild.getValue().toLowerCase().equals(actualNewChild.getValue().toLowerCase())) || (actualOldChild.getValue().toLowerCase() != null && actualNewChild.getValue().toLowerCase() == null) || (actualOldChild.getValue().toLowerCase() == null && actualNewChild.getValue().toLowerCase() != null));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            if (actualOldChild.hasAttributes()) {
                                if (!this.diffNodeAttributes(actualOldChild, actualNewChild)) {
                                    matched = true;
                                }
                                else {
                                    attributesChanged = true;
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                matched = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    actualIndex = (Integer) newMe.getKey();
                }

                if (matched || valueChanged || attributesChanged) {
                    oldRoot = actualOldChild;
                    newRoot = newChildren.get(actualIndex);
                    oldPath = oldPath + "/" + oldRoot.getNodeName() + "-" + oldMe.getKey();
                    newPath = newPath + "/" + newRoot.getNodeName() + "-" + actualIndex;
                    oldIter.remove();
                    newIter.remove();
                    oldChildren.remove(oldMe.getKey());
                    newChildren.remove(actualIndex);
                    if (matched) {
                        this.compare(oldRoot, oldPath, newRoot, newPath);
                    } else if (valueChanged) {
                        this.differences.add("value modified : " + oldPath + " } " + newPath + " : " + oldRoot.getValue() + " changed to " + newRoot.getValue());
                    }
                    else if(attributesChanged) {
                        this.differences.add("attributes changed : " + oldPath + " } " + newPath);
                    }
                    this.compare(oldRoot, oldPath, newRoot, newPath);
                    oldPath = memoryOldPath;
                    newPath = memoryNewPath;
                }
            }

            for (int i : oldChildren.keySet()) {
                this.getDifferences().add("deleted : " + oldPath + "/" + oldChildren.get(i).getNodeName() + "-" + i + " } " + newPath);
            }

            for (int j : newChildren.keySet()) {
                this.getDifferences().add("added : " + oldPath + " } " + newPath + "/" + newChildren.get(j).getNodeName() + "-" + j);
            }
        }

        else if ((!oldRoot.hasChildren() && newRoot.hasChildren()) || (oldRoot.hasChildren() && !newRoot.hasChildren())) {
            this.getDifferences().add("structure modified : " + oldPath + " } " + newPath);
        }

        else if (!oldRoot.hasChildren() && !newRoot.hasChildren()) {
            this.diffNodeValue(oldRoot, oldPath, newRoot, newPath);
        }
    }

    public int findIdChild(List<Element> children) {
        int result = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.getIdDefinitions().size(); i++) {
            String name = this.getIdDefinitions().get(i);
            for (int k = 0; k < children.size(); k++) {
                if (children.get(k).getName().equals(name)) {
                    result = k;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (result != -1) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Did you profile it? What did that show? Where are the bottlenecks?

Comment: Also, do you have to write your own? https://superuser.com/questions/79920/how-can-i-diff-two-xml-files

Answer (score 1):

You have two nested while loops, where most of your comparisons are pretty deep in nested logic.  You've basically written this to be O(n*n) or O(n^2).

Also, you go through some unnecessary looping moving found differences into data structures accumulating them.  In fact, most of this class goes out-of-the way to separate the data from the algorithm, which means that every time you want to get to the data, it is an extra stack frame to get the "data" object.

You're constantly calling to lower case for comparison, which violates the spirit of XML, because XML is case sensitive, but assuming you need to, stop doing it right before the comparison.  It constructs too many new strings on the heap.  You might get a small boost by using `String.equalsIgnoreCase(...)`.

Also, I would avoid the use of iterators to reduce the pressure on your heap.  Iterators are objects that wrap the index within a `List` and that object then gets stored on the heap.  This means extra stack frames at runtime, and higher ram usage.  Rewriting to use the less-object-oriented three-stanza for loops might read less cleanly, but could speed up the execution a little.

The better solution would be to index one tree first, with the key of the index being something that is trivial to search for using a hash of the key.  Then while walking the other tree, you can quickly lookup if the expected value is present.  This would be a major rewrite, but you should be able to get the complexity down to a O(n log n) performance profile, which will allow you to process larger files faster.  Of course, there is a limit, and eventually O(n log n) might not be fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is using [DOM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/index.html) for parsing XML, so you're reading the whole document into memory before parsing. This takes much more time and memory than [SAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/index.html) or [StAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/index.html) approach, which are intended for reading and processing XML element by element.

Imagine that you're comparing two *huge* `xml` files which differ in the very first tag. With *DOM* approach you will first read them both in memory and then compare. With *SAX/StAX* approach you will be notified by xml processor that some element is reached, so you can compare it's value to the corresponding element (if it does exist) in second `xml`, which will allow you to detect differences faster than with *DOM* approach.

Comment: It is kind of hard to do comparison without having all the elements.  I agree that DOM puts memory pressure on performance, but this block of code already has the documents processed and stored in RAM.  A StAX approach is great for finding a differing node, as you describe, but if your goal is to find all differing nodes, you'd have a StAX processing for each node, which is suboptimal.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly what's making your code so slow, but at a quick glance I see you have many, many iterators; if you're using an iterator on to go through an xml file with 10,000 items, against another xml file with 10,000 items, you have 100,000,000 calculations to perform.

I recently created a similar comparison program, however it wasn't for XML files.
My process was firstly to put all the items into multiple HashMaps, and wrap them all into a CachedDatabase class. The keys were generated in such a way so that both the old and new maps would have the same keys for different items, even if the value had changed. I don't know if this is applicable in your scenario.

My advice would be to figure out the most appropriate data structures for each comparable item. HashMaps and HashSet's are great because look up time is O(1) complexity, meaning that I didn't have to traverse the entire map to check for an item.

I'll return to this question in like an hour or two and see if I can answer it more fully for you.